# Android Pagination library in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, pagination, android-livedata

How can I use the pagination library in the `ArrayAdapter` (I dont want to use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`)?
`categories` is a list of string to be shown. I have a huge list of categories. I want it to be paginated. How to achieve this?

```
List<String> categories = getSomeCategories();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, categories);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a method which returns the `LiveData<PagedList<String> categories`. I'm using the `LivePagedListBuilder` to build it. I want my adapter to observe on this.

Comment: Its better to use RecyclerView and Paging Library [Here](https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe) you can find some help

Comment: I want to use it in the AutocompleteTextView

Comment: Then I don't think so paging library available for list view, Better to go with this [Solution](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the scrolls using the recycler view's OnScrollListener, then check if the visible element is the last element in page, and if so load another page.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

  @Override
  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    int visibleItemsCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemsCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int pastVisibleItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int lastCompletelyVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    if (dy >= 0
        && (visibleItemsCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemsCount
        && lastCompletelyVisibleItem == elements.size() - 1) {
      offset = elements.size();
      //Start at this offset
      populateRecyclerView(offset);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to use pagination library

Comment: Hmmm, I use this method and it works flawlessly. btw I updated the answer above with the code needed to achieve this.

Comment: I know the above code works, but my requirement is completely different. I don't need recycler view. I'm using ArrayAdapter on AutocompleteTextView.